# Integer Palindrome Check in C

Tags: beginner, c, palindrome

This method should check whether a number is a palindrome or not:

```
typedef enum { false, true } Bool;

Bool is_pal(int n) {
  Bool is_pal_helper(const char *arr, size_t size);

  char temp[12];                         // INT_MIN == '-' + 10 digits (+ null-Terminator)
  sprintf(temp, "%d", n);
  return is_pal_helper(temp, strlen(temp));
}

Bool is_pal_helper(const char *arr, size_t size) {
  if (size <= 1)
    return true;

  if (*arr != *(arr+size-1))
    return false;

  return is_pal_helper(arr+1, size - 2);
}
```

This was my intuitive solution and I was wondering, if it would be more efficient to keep the number an `int`, copy and reverse (with modulo and divide-operations) the `int` and check whether the (*reversed*) copy is equal to the original `int`.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I wanted to reverse the decimal number. `12345` -> `54321`, but the solutions below seem pretty solid to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few notes:

- Why aren't you using [`stdbool.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html)?  Use that instead of rolling your own.
- Why are you using recursion?  If you're looking for efficiency, [you will use iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15688105/1937270) in almost every single circumstance.
- Why are you constraining yourself to just `int`s as palindromes if you are already accepting a string with your helper?  If you want to stay true to this you could keep your method that you have (with a few changes):

  ```
  bool isIntPalindrome(int n)
  {
      // palindromes only apply to the natural numbers
      if (n < 0) return false;

      // INT_MAX == 32767 + '\0' -> 6
      // double that to be safe on weird machines 
      char temp[12];
      sprintf(temp, "%d", n);
      return isPalindrome(temp);
  }
  ```

---

Here's my take on your problem, should be faster.  I'll provide speed test results in a bit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool isPalindrome(char* str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    for (char *ptr1 = str, *ptr2 = str + len - 1; ptr2 >= ptr1; ptr1++, ptr2--)
    {
        // not super strict check, just test if same lowercase ASCII value
        if(tolower(*ptr1) != tolower(*ptr2)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    puts(isPalindrome("123454321") ? "true" : "false");
    puts(isPalindrome("12") ? "true" : "false");
    puts(isPalindrome("racecar") ? "true" : "false");
    puts(isPalindrome("test") ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Output:

> ```
> $ time ./op
> true
> false
> # had to exclude string examples
>
> real  0m0.025s
> user  0m0.011s
> sys   0m0.012s
>
> $ time ./syb0rg
> true
> false
> true
> false
>
> real  0m0.006s
> user  0m0.001s
> sys   0m0.002s
> ```

Now the resulting time differences aren't that big, but my code didn't try and put the method to its limits to really see how it would perform with something a bit bigger for example.  But in the end mine is a bit faster!

Comment: I would suggest to have a convenience method `bool isPalindrome(int number)` which converts to string to match original request.

Comment: @holroy Added and improved

Comment: That won't work on machines where `INT_MAX` isn't 32767...

Comment: @Barry True, edited in fix

Comment: Thanks for the review! The iterative solution is indeed faster, I only chose the recursive approach here, since I just learned about recursion. I didn't want to use `<stdbool.h>`, since I'm not sure whether it's supported in all C versions. Is this a serious problem, or can I safely use `<stdbool.h>` in the future? As @Barry already mentioned ÌNT_MAX`is not always 32767 (for example `sizeof(int)` is `4 bytes` on my machine, which results in `(2^32)/2 -1 = 2147483647`as ÌNT_MAX`.

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive Yes, if your compiler is compliant with the standards then it must include that header; and most compilers are compliant. The size of an `int` isn't actually defined by the C Standard, hence that value can vary from machine to machine.

Comment: @syb0rg Awesome, now I'm finally sure about the <stdbool.h> goodness in the future!

Comment: @syb0rg. Did you time yours with the integer to string conversion? Or just with the string palindrome testing?

Comment: @holroy Both, and they performed about the same.

Answer (score 6):

**`sprintf` has a return**

`sprintf` has a return that you can use. You don't need `strlen()`:

```
char temp[12];
int len = sprintf(temp, "%d", n);
return is_pal_helper(temp, len);
```

**Prefer indexing**

Indexing is easier to read than pointer arithmetic. I'd prefer checking this way:

```
if (arr[0] != arr[size-1])
```

**Recursion is unnecessary**

It's actually easier to write `is_pal_helper` as a loop:

```
Bool is_pal_helper(const char *arr, size_t size) {
    for (; size > 1; size -= 2, ++arr) {
        if (arr[0] != arr[size-1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

At which point, you don't even need it:

```
Bool is_pal(int n) {
    char temp[12];
    int size = sprintf(temp, "%d", n);

    const char *p = temp;
    for (; size > 1; size -= 2, ++p) {
        if (p[0] != p[size-1]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Prefer full names**

`is_palindrome` is clear. `is_pal` sounds to me like you're checking if the number is your friend.

Comment: Is there are reason why you prefer to use `p[0]` and `++p` instead of a loop counter and `p[i]`? And similar for doing calculation on `size`? To me it kind of reads a little strange as you _seem_ to only ever test on the first and last character.

Comment: Thank you really much, for you review. I just did it with recursion, because I just learned about recursion and wanted to test myself a little, but the iterative solution seems more intuitive and cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers has focused a little on the aspects related to pointer arithmetic and iterative vs recursion. However you ask a question related to using div/mod to reverse the integer which hasn't been addressed.

But first lets comment a little upon style:

- *Use full names for variables and function names* – It is better to have good names like `is_palindrome` or `is_palindrome_helper`, as long as we're not talking about standard abbreviations like `str`, or loop counters like `i` or possibly `temp`
- *Be consistent with spacing around operators* – I would suggest always using space after comma, and around operators. Use `(*arr != *(arr + size - 1)` and `is_pal_helper(arr + 1, size -2)`, and not remove spaces some places
- *I suggest **always** using braces around blocks* – This is somewhat controversial, but I suggest to always use braces around blocks, even if the block is a one-liner. At some point in time, this will save you hours of greiving when you don't find the flaw in your logic and it is due to wrongful indentation and missing braces around blocks.
- *Be consistent in brace style* – Some prefer to let the starting brace be on its own line, and some prefer on the end of the previous line. Whichever style you choose, be consistent. Barry is consistent having them on the previous line, and syb0rg on a new line. Choose either, but *be consistent*
- As the other answers suggests, there are options related to extension of your methods. Like do you allow `-12321` to be a palindrome? Or is `RACecar` a palindrome? Syb0rg suggests, by using `tolower()`, that the latter should be a palindrome, whilst all the examples would fail on the `-12321` being a palindrome. This could be handled using convenience methods to allow the user to specify this.

### `isPalindrome()` with extensions

Using the answer of syb0rg as a base I implemented the extension to allow for different variations of the `isPalindrome()` function. To separate between calling it with a string or an int, with all of them ending up within the `str` version. As you don't have function parameter overloading in C (nor default parameters) I ended up calling them with different names.

Here is the code with a little testing at the end:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


bool isPalindromeStr_(char* str, bool useTolower)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    printf("Testing: %s, lower: %d - ", str, useTolower);
    for (char *ptr1 = str, *ptr2 = str + len - 1; ptr2 >= ptr1; ptr1++, ptr2--)
    {
        // not super strict check, just test if same ASCII value
        if ( (useTolower && (tolower(*ptr1) != tolower(*ptr2)))
           || (!useTolower && *ptr1 != *ptr2) )
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}

bool isPalindromeStr(char* str)
{
    return isPalindromeStr_(str, false);
}

bool isPalindromeInt_(int number, bool allowNegativePalindromes)
{
    char temp[12];

    if (allowNegativePalindromes)
    {
       number = -1 * number;
    }

    sprintf(temp, "%d", number);
    return isPalindromeStr(temp); 
}

bool isPalindromeInt(int number)
{
    return isPalindromeInt_(number, false);
}


int main(void)
{
   // The longer text is the expected variant...
   puts(isPalindromeInt(12321) ? "Correct" : "wrong");
   puts(isPalindromeInt(123321) ? "Correct" : "wrong");
   puts(isPalindromeInt(-34543) ? "Correct" : "No, disallowing negative palindromes");
   puts(isPalindromeInt_(-34543, true) ? "Yes, allowing negative palindromes" : "wrong");
   puts(isPalindromeStr("racecar") ? "Correct" : "wrong");
   puts(isPalindromeStr("rAcECAR") ? "Wrong, shouldn't be in-case-sensitive" : "Nope, case difference");
   puts(isPalindromeStr_("rAcECAR", true) ? "Yes, in-case-sensitive" : "Wrong");
   puts(isPalindromeStr("not at all") ? "Wrong" : "Correct");
}
```

And this outputs as expected:

```
./palindrome 
Testing: 12321, lower: 0 - Correct
Testing: 123321, lower: 0 - Correct
Testing: -34543, lower: 0 - No, disallowing negative palindromes
Testing: 34543, lower: 0 - Yes, allowing negative palindromes
Testing: racecar, lower: 0 - Correct
Testing: rAcECAR, lower: 0 - Nope, case difference
Testing: rAcECAR, lower: 1 - Yes, in-case-sensitive
Testing: not at all, lower: 0 - Correct
```

Notice there is an extraneous output within the `isPalindromeStr_()` version.

### `isPalindrome` using div and mod

I then ventured on to test how the integer version could be implemented using div and mod, and ended up with the following version:

```
bool isPalindromeInt_(int number, bool allowNegativePalindromes)
{
    int reverseNumber = 0;
    int tmp;

    if (allowNegativePalindromes)
    {
       number = -1 * number;
    }

    tmp = number;
    while (tmp > 0)
    {
      reverseNumber = reverseNumber*10 + tmp % 10;
      tmp = tmp / 10;
    }
    return reverseNumber == number;
}
```

I left in the option to allow for negative palindromes in this version, which could be removed if one is so inclined. Devised a little test scheme where I called the integer version with the numbers `12321`, `123123`and `54321` in a loop with 100 000 repeats. It turns out that on my computer this runs in less than half the time of versions using conversion to string. (In my test the iterative and recursive version had almost identical timings!)

### Conclusion

Your version does solve the task, albeit it has some minor style issues. An iterative version can be used, and has it benefits like it's easier to extend into various version which all ends up in the same code.

And finally, a solution using div and mod is in preliminary tests almost twice as fast when it comes to deciding if an integer is a palindrome or not!

<sub>**PS!** Thanks to Bob for pointing out that I'd forgotten to include the last code segment!</sub>

Comment: Thank you really much, you brought some more aspects into this review!

Comment: I just implemented everything mentioned in this post and noticed something (in my opinion) pretty interesting. First the iterative (`105ms`) and recursive (`110ms`) solutions easily outperformed the reversed (`198ms`) solution, but after turning on optimisation flags, the reverse-integer solution finished around four times faster (iterative: `94ms`, recursive:`'87ms`, reverse: `17ms`)... I did *100 000* tests with *10* test cases each (different results/length) for every algorithm.